# How does libtool determine the suffix on error cannot install 'xxx' to a directory not ending in //lib?

Tags: docker, libtool

I want to build lely-core: https://gitlab.com/lely_industries/lely-core using conan2 inside a docker container.

I can reproduce this without conan.
Build steps:

```
autoreconf -i
./configure --disable-cython --disable-python --disable-python2 --disable-python3 --disable-doc
make -j16
mkdir -p ./_package/local/usr
make install prefix=$(Absolute Path to _package folder)/local/usr
```

When I build without docker everything works.
When I build with my docker container I get this error:

> error: cannot install 'liblely-tap.la' to a directory not ending in //lib

How does libtool determine the suffix //lib? I assume this is an environment problem, but I couldn't find which variables are used.

Comment: Building an Autoconf-based tool in a container, I probably would set neither `./configure --prefix` nor `make install prefix=`, and just let the package install into `/usr/local` in the image.  Is that possible for you, and does it avoid the error?

Comment: i would like to avoid this because it is cross compiled. But i have a workaround right now i tracked it down that libtool had diffrent versions. (The Docker container had a newer Version.) I switched to an older Version of the Container and it works for now. I still would like to know how libtool determins this path to probably fix this.

Comment: I still not found the code that determens the prefix. But i found the Changelog: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libtool.git/tree/NEWS